# Unable to start zookeeper services exiting with "Severe unrecoverable error"

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm unable to start zookeeper services. Please see the stack traces.

- **Trace 1 :** org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer:

  ```
  Severe unrecoverable error, exiting
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.40003a3c3 (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileSnap.serialize(FileSnap.java:225)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.save(FileTxnSnapLog.java:275)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.takeSnapshot(ZooKeeperServer.java:270)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.SyncRequestProcessor$1.run(SyncRequestProcessor.java:123)
  ```
- **Trace 2:** org.apache.zookeeper.server.SyncRequestProcessor:

  ```
  Severe unrecoverable error, exiting
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/zookeeper/version-2/log.40003a3c5 (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog.append(FileTxnLog.java:205)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.append(FileTxnSnapLog.java:347)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.append(ZKDatabase.java:476)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.SyncRequestProcessor.run(SyncRequestProcessor.java:110)
  ```

I've tried -

1. Changing ownership to zookeeper:zookeeper.
2. Changing permission level to 755 and at last 777 for `/var/lib/zookeeper`.
3. Override default dataLogDir and dataDir to `/var/lib/zookeeper2`
4. Removing the zookeeper role services from the server and adding back again.
5. Decommissioning of full server and added again in the cluster server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use '/var/lib/ folder as dataDir? '/var/lib' folder is a special folder and generally used by os packages.

If you change dataDir and dataLogDir to a user specific location it will work.

Comment: This path by default taken by CDH installation. I haven't changed anything much related to path. Also, it was working fine for last 3 months.